# Validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So first I had this class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name


end
```

and was able to create and save users in ruby sandbox.

Then I added validation like this:

```
validates(:name, presence: true)
```

saved my changes, went back to console, and said this:

```
>> user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
>> user.save
```

It should return FALSE because name is blank. But it returned true. Why?
Maybe I should restart the sandbox console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
reload!
```

in the console.

This will reload your models and should pick up the new validation. This makes it unnecessary to restart the console. I use this like a bajillion times a day. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes never mind. I restarted the sandbox console and now validation is working correctly.